# What is the best practice to support dark and light mode for an inapp in react-native

Tags: react-native

I need to set dark and light mode only in my app settings. Not the entire device or app.

What is the best practice to acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a react-native package for dark-mode in-app feature [react-native-dark-mode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dark-mode). else you can do it yourself by following [this](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/react-native-dark-mode-and-theming-dc299bec206d)

Answer (score 0):

use Context api for theming in react native

```
const lightTheme={
   color: 'white',
   fontColor: 'black',
};

const darkTheme={
   color: 'black',
   fontColor: 'white',
};

<ThemeProvider theme={theme="light" ? lightTheme: darkTheme}>
  <app/>
</ThemeProvider>
```

check context api documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

check example of using context api for theme [here](https://github.com/adambene/reactnative-themeapp/blob/master/ThemeApp.js)

Comment: check example app https://github.com/adambene/reactnative-themeapp